# How to write an expression in RDLC to select only distinct values from the dataset

Tags: rdlc

I have a table(Customer) which contains RequestId column having many duplicate values. I want to take only the distnct values. How to write an expression in RDLC?

Answer (score 1):

In `RDLC Tablix` you can group data in order to display distinct value; in your case you can group by `RequestId`.